# text mining and cross referencing

Tags: text-manipulation

I want to make an adjacency matrix with citations.

I want to conduct make an index of 130 words and search 130 papers against the 130 words. Manually this is a long process. But I want to automate the searching.

Can anyone suggest if this can be done with text mining or any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Probably off-topic, because I don't know how to do this in LaTeX but you could use `pdftotext` to convert the pdfs to text, then scan that for your search terms and count the number of occurences:

```
pdftotext input.pdf - | grep "search term" | wc -l
```

You could then use Python to build a table of the number of occurences

```
import subprocess
import os
import numpy as np

pdf_folder = '/path/to/folder'
pdfs = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f)) and os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == '.pdf']
search_terms = ['search', 'me']
latex_filename = 'citematrix.tex'
pdf_fullpaths = [os.path.join(pdf_folder, pdf) for pdf in pdfs]
cite_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(search_terms), len(pdfs)), dtype=np.int)

for y, search_term in enumerate(search_terms):
    for x, pdf in enumerate(pdf_fullpaths):
        pdftotext = subprocess.Popen(['pdftotext', pdf, '-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i', search_term], stdin=pdftotext.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        wc = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        count = int([c.strip() for c in wc.stdout][0])
        cite_matrix[y, x] = count
```

You could then write all pdf filenames where the search term was found into a latex file:

```
latex = '\\documentclass{article}\n\\begin{document}\n'

for y, search_term in enumerate(search_terms):
    latex += search_term + ': '
    if np.sum(cite_matrix[y]) < 1:
        latex += 'No occurence'
        continue
    occurences = 0
    for x, pdf in enumerate(pdfs):
        if cite_matrix[y, x] < 1:
            continue
        if occurences > 0:
            latex += ', '
        latex += pdf
        occurences += 1
latex += '\n\\end{document}'

with open(latex_filename, 'w') as out:
    out.write(latex)
```

or if you know the corresponding bibtex keys you could cite them:

```
bibtex_keys = ['Author2019', 'Buthor2020']
bib_filename = 'refs.bib'

latex = '\\documentclass{article}\n\\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}\n\\addbibresource{'+bib_filename+'}\n\\begin{document}\n'
for y, search_term in enumerate(search_terms):
    latex += search_term + ': '
    if np.sum(cite_matrix[y]) < 1:
        latex += 'No occurence'
        continue
    latex += '\\cite{'
    occurences = 0
    for x, key in enumerate(bibtex_keys):
        if cite_matrix[y, x] > 0:
            if occurences > 0:
                latex += ', '
            latex += key
            occurences += 1
    latex += '}\n\n'
latex += '\\printbibliography\n\\end{document}'

with open(latex_filename, 'w') as out:
    out.write(latex)
```

or you could write the whole table to an excel sheet...

Comment: THank you so much. Can you suggest how to do it in r?